# IntelliSense: namespace "MSXML2" has no member "DOMDocument" in VS2012

Tags: c++, xml

I am trying to compile a project I inherited, and then encountered this error. Here are some relevant code:

```
#include <msxml.h>
...
HRESULT hr;
hr = pDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument));
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I later went to the defination of MSXML2, and change DOMDocument into IXMLDOMDocument, now the project can run, while I still don't know why

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found this solution can just allow the project to be compiled, leaving the program run abnormally...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am seeing similar issues in Windows 8.  It seems that MSXML 6.0 does not expose DOMDocument, but it does expose DOMDocument60.  To help others get here via a search, the compiler error you may also see is:
error C2039: 'DOMDocument' : is not a member of 'MSXML2'

Try making the following change to use the 6.0 interface explicitly:

```
#import "msxml6.dll"
...
HRESULT hr;
hr = pDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));
```

I see that others have this issue but in the context of Excel automation.  See that discussion [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/f9180e5c-7c2f-44be-8415-d0d2b76e3f7f/).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved this problem about one month ago, but forgot to post the solution here...