# VS2015：“DOMDocument60”: is not a member of 'MSXML2'

Tags: c++, msxml6

Environment：

```
    IDE --> VS2015
    Operating System --> WinServer 2012
```

I use MSXML to build my programme. The project **works well on windows7**. When I builded it on winServer 2012. It got the compling error:

```
 “DOMDocument60”: is not a member of 'MSXML'
```

I have looked up the %systemdir%  and found the `msxml6.dll` and other `msxml*.dll`

```
msxml4rc.dll
msxml6.dll
msxml3.dll
msxml6r.dll.mui
msxml3r.dll.mui
msxml6r.dll
msxml3r.dll
```

It seems the operating system has installed the MSXML6.0. I can't figure out why, has any suggestion ? Thanks  for any comment! : )

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413055/intellisense-namespace-msxml2-has-no-member-domdocument-in-vs2012)

Comment: Thanks soooo much ! It's exactly what I want !